# pandas: bdate_range first set sunday as first day of week

Tags: python, pandas, calendar

Is there a way to get a business date range where Sunday through Thursday are treated as business days and

Example output:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.bdate_range('2016-5-10','2016-5-17')
DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-10', '2016-05-11', '2016-05-12', '2016-05-13',
           '2016-05-16', '2016-05-17'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Desired output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-10', '2016-05-11', '2016-05-12', '2016-05-15',
           '2016-05-16', '2016-05-17'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [custom business days](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental):

```
weekmask = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu'
custombday = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask=weekmask)

print pd.bdate_range('2016-5-10','2016-5-17', freq=custombday)

DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-10', '2016-05-11', '2016-05-12', '2016-05-15',
               '2016-05-16', '2016-05-17'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter out the days that you don't want:

```
dates=pd.date_range('2016-5-10','2016-5-17').to_frame(name='d')  # convert to frame so we can run query on it
dates.query('d.dt.strftime("%a") not in ["Fri","Sat"]').index
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-10', '2016-05-11', '2016-05-12', '2016-05-15',
               '2016-05-16', '2016-05-17'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

here i'm using query for filtering out. you can see it's very easy to pick only the days that you do want, instead of filtering out.


about code -

```
d.dt.strftime("%a")
```

it will give you the timestamp as day name only, like Sun Mon..